# NoClassDefFoundError in Hibernate-JPA over EJB Stateless Bean

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I'm currently configuring my project setup of my first official EJB Project. I've set up all my POJOs on a single layer EJB Module called Model and in another EJB Module called Controller, from there I'm trying to execute a simple select from database using the JPA on the Model Module.
I'm not using datasource definitions on JNDI, all my connection params are set in the persistence.xml and when I try them locally within the Model Module it works fine, in other words, running a simple main method on the Model Module works fine with all the POJOs, but as soon as I call the same method through a stateless SessionBean is giving me the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.opus.utils.Hibernate5Test.<init>(Hibernate5Test.java:30)
    at com.opus.utils.Hibernate5Test.newInstance(Hibernate5Test.java:43)
    at com.opus.ejb.beans.TestSessionBean.getRoleById(TestSessionBean.java:24)
    at com.opus.classes.ControllerTest.testing(ControllerTest.java:20)
    at com.opus.classes.ControllerTest.main(ControllerTest.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.xml.Origin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

I am using JBoss 6 and a MySQL database. Here is the code for the Stateless SessionBean:

```
package com.myproject.ejb.beans;

import com.myproject.dao.DAOrole;
import com.myproject.jpa.pojos.Role;
import com.myproject.utils.Hibernate5Test;
import com.myproject.utils.PrintLog;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;

@Stateful
public class TestSessionBean implements TestSessionBeanLocal {

// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
// "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
public Object getRoleById(long id){
    PrintLog log = new PrintLog("myproject-ejb");
    Hibernate5Test hib5 = Hibernate5Test.newInstance();
    if(hib5.entityMngr!=null){
        // Test para roles y llaves complejas con Menu
        DAOrole daoRole = new DAOrole(hib5.entityMngr,"testingHib5");
        Role role = daoRole.selectById(id);
        log.println("Hibernate5Test", "main", "testingHib5", role.showInfo());
        return role;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Here is the code for the Hibernate Manager:

```
package com.myproject.utils;
import com.myproject.dao.DAOrole;
import com.myproject.jpa.pojos.Role;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Hibernate5Test {

public EntityManager entityMngr;
public EntityManagerFactory factory;

private static Hibernate5Test hib5 = null;

private Hibernate5Test(){
    try{
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myproject-Model-PU");
        entityMngr = factory.createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("Connection Succesfull!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        entityMngr = null;
        System.out.println("Connection failed!");
    }
}

public static Hibernate5Test newInstance(){
    if(hib5 ==null)
        return new Hibernate5Test();
    else
        return hib5;
}

public void close(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Closing Factory and EntityManager...");
        entityMngr.close();
        factory.close();
        System.out.println("Closed.");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code for the EJB client on the Controller Module:

```
package com.myproject.classes;

import com.myproject.ejb.beans.TestSessionBean;
import com.myproject.jpa.pojos.Role;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class ControllerTest {
@EJB
TestSessionBean test = new TestSessionBean();

public void testing(long roleId){
    Role role = (Role)test.getRoleById(roleId);
    role.showInfo();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ControllerTest test = new ControllerTest();
    test.testing(new Long(1));
}
}
```

Any help it would be appreciated, maybe I'm misunderstanding the way EJB works.

Comment: Looks like you miss `hibernate-core.jar` in your classpath

Comment: I added the reference for the hibernate-core within my Controller project and it didn´t work. I just tried adding the directory to the actual CLASSPATH and still the same problem. I do not understand how EJB recognizes the JPA connection within EJB Modules.

Comment: How are you performing your tests? Is JBoss running through your IDE or through the command line? Why are you both injecting and instantiating your EJB on your `ControllerTest`? That's simply wrong...

Comment: Take care when you use injection to instantiate objects and reserved words like new to do the same...